# pandas change date format if start date is superior to end date

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm cleaning a data where values are dates,

Sometimes I find values for a given event where the start date is superior to the end date.

After looking to values I have noticed that it's due to wrong datetime formatting during data collection.

In some row it's yy-mm-dd and others row its yy-dd-mm.

The right format should be yy-mm-dd.

Here is the data

```
     start_date end_date
0   2018-05-29  2018-04-06
7   2018-08-01  2018-03-30
5   2018-08-13  2018-06-09
3   2018-12-02  2018-02-15
11  2018-08-24  2018-05-09
12  2018-04-20  2018-02-05
1   2018-07-30  2018-03-08
8   2018-08-16  2018-03-09
10  2018-09-07  2018-07-20
```

Basically what I want is to check for every row, if start_date is superior to end_date, change the format of end_date or start date until end_date become superior to the start date.

ex: for the first row:
I need to change the end date to 2018-06-04, 
but for the second row, it's start date that needs to be changed to 2018-01-08

Any ideas?

Comment: My question would be: why? In other words, you just gave a condition which tells _if something_ has to be done in a row (start > end). But I don't understand what is the reason for _what_ has to be done, ie changing start_date or end_date.

Comment: By common sense, an event should never end before it has started! , that is why I want to change.

Comment: What happens if either "swap" could work? Consider the case where you have `2018-05-03` as start, `2018-04-05` as end. Do these become (in yyyy-mm-dd) `2018-05-03` and `2018-05-04` or `2018-03-05` and `2018-04-05`?

Comment: if this happens, will get the first `2018-05-03` and `2018-05-04`

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi but that will be inaccurate

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm not sure if this helps, but let's see...

*I'd like to state first, that IMO trying to repair data which was corrupted when read in might be dangerous - perhaps your assumption* how *it was corrupted is not completely correct.*
However:

With

```
    df.apply(lambda d: d.dt.day > 12)
Out: 
    start_date  end_date
0         True     False
7        False      True
5         True     False
3        False      True
11        True     False
12        True     False
1         True     False
8         True     False
10       False      True
```

we can see that in all rows (that I have access to) *either* start *or* end have a day >12, which would obviously not suit as a month. I.e., we can use

```
mask = df.start_date.dt.day > 12
```

as an indexer for changing the part where it's possible on the start side separately from the part on the end side, i.e. the parts where day values are not greater than 12:

```
df[~mask].start_date.apply(lambda d: pd.datetime(d.year, d.day, d.month))
Out: 
7    2018-01-08
3    2018-02-12
10   2018-07-09
Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and

```
df[mask].end_date.apply(lambda d: pd.datetime(d.year, d.day, d.month))
Out: 
0    2018-06-04
5    2018-09-06
11   2018-09-05
12   2018-05-02
1    2018-08-03
8    2018-09-03
Name: end_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So if applied:

```
df.start_date[~mask] = df[~mask].start_date.apply(lambda d: pd.datetime(d.year, d.day, d.month))
df.end_date[mask] = df[mask].end_date.apply(lambda d: pd.datetime(d.year, d.day, d.month))
```

this leads to

```
df
Out: 
   start_date   end_date
0  2018-05-29 2018-06-04
7  2018-01-08 2018-03-30
5  2018-08-13 2018-09-06
3  2018-02-12 2018-02-15
11 2018-08-24 2018-09-05
12 2018-04-20 2018-05-02
1  2018-07-30 2018-08-03
8  2018-08-16 2018-09-03
10 2018-07-09 2018-07-20
```

which has no starts later than ends anymore:

```
df.start_date > df.end_date
Out: 
0     False
7     False
5     False
3     False
11    False
12    False
1     False
8     False
10    False
dtype: bool
```